# Django rest framework token authentication AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

I am fairly new to Django and Token authentication as well as AngularJS. So far I have made Django backend and AngularJS frontend. I installed the Django Rest Framework and got the standard token authentication working as far as doing:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $http.post('link to my api', {
      'username': $scope.data.username,
      'password': $scope.data.password,
    }).success(function () {
      $state.go('tab');
    })
      .error(function () {

      });
  };
```

So far I succeed by getting a token with the right username and password. I see so much options about authentication that I don't know what fits for me anymore and where to start as I don't get a lot of information on the standard Token authentication. I have an Ionic app with a login screen, the Django backend has the users stored. I want to be able to login with a user account that resides within the Django database. Whenever that is done the user got permission to use the app. Later on it should be possible for example to get the credentials like personal details of the logged in user. Let's say I use the TokenAuthentication like above, I get the token. But how can I get the user credentials or whatever else from Django later on by that token? I am totally lost. If someone could please bring me into the right approach and material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when you implement the following DRF permissions:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

and you make viewsets like on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example that it automatically requires a token to view those viewsets. So then you could work with that token to send requests to the api to get specific data.